# How redirect mobile users to different url?

Tags: javascript, mobile, tablet

I used the following script to redirect mobile users to a mobile site:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (screen.width < 800) {
        var ref = document.referrer;
        var urls = new Array("http://www.ilsanlorenzo.net","http://www.ilsanlorenzo.net/mobsite");
        var n = ref.match(urls[0]);
        var m = ref.match(urls[1]);
        if ((m!==null) || (n!==null)) {
            stop;
        } else if (ref=='') {
            var r = confirm("Small Display is Detected.\nClick \"OK\" for MOBILE SITE.");
            if (r==true) {
                window.location = "http://www.ilsanlorenzo.net/mobsite";
            } else {
                stop;
            }
        } else {
            window.location = "http://www.ilsanlorenzo.net/mobsite";
        }
    }
</script>
```

I would like to know if anyone knows a script to redirect mobile users to a mobile site version and tablet and desktop users to a web site version.
Does anyone know a solution?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: window.location = "http://www.ilsanlorenzo.net/mobsite"; should be 
window.location.href = "http://www.ilsanlorenzo.net/mobsite";

Comment: We have not understood maybe, but I would like to know if anyone knows suggest a script to redirect mobile users to a mobile site version and tablet and desktop users to a web site version

Comment: Oh I see, instead of what you have written?  You could use media queries if the only changes are in css, or https://github.com/PaulKinlan/formfactor  to load different resources based on formfactor (tablet, phone, desktop)

Comment: No changes are almost complete so I would need a more appropriate code